# Flink TaskManager livenessProbe doesn't work

Tags: apache-flink

I'm following this [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html#session-cluster-resource-definitions) to configure probes for JobManager and TaskManager on Kubernetes.

JobManager works perfectly, but TaskManager doesn't work. I noticed in the pod log that the liveness probe failed:

```
  Normal   Killing    3m36s                 kubelet, gke-dagang-test-default-pool-494df2ba-vhs5  Killing container with id docker://taskmanager:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Warning  Unhealthy  37s (x8 over 7m37s)   kubelet, gke-dagang-test-default-pool-494df2ba-vhs5  Liveness probe failed: dial tcp 10.20.1.54:6122: connect: connection refused
```

I'm wondering does TM actually listen on 6122?

Flink version: 1.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is because I didn't add `taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122` in flink-config.yaml, now it works perfectly.